# Loading XML document loads the same group twice

Tags: c#, .net, xml, list, xmlserializer

Some classes to start, I'm writing them all so you can reproduce my problem:

```
public class PermissionObject
{
    public string permissionName;
    public string permissionObject;
    public bool permissionGranted;

    public PermissionObject()
    {
        permissionName = "";
        permissionObject = "";
        permissionGranted = true;
    }

    public PermissionObject(string name, string obj, bool granted)
    {
        permissionName = name;
        permissionObject = obj;
        permissionGranted = granted;
    }
}

public class Config
{
    public string cmsDataPath = "";
    public string cmsIP = "";
    public List<UserClass> usersCMS = new List<UserClass>();
    static public string pathToConfig = @"E:\testconpcms.xml";
    public string cardServerAddress = "";

    public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(pathToConfig, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fileStream, this);
        }
    }

    public static Config Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(pathToConfig))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
            try
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(pathToConfig, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    return (Config)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Config();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class UserClass
{
    public string Name;
    public string Login;
    public string Password;
    public PCMS2 PermissionsList; // OR new PCMS1, as I will explain in a bit

    public UserClass()
    {
        this.Name = "Admin";
        this.Login = "61-64-6D-69-6E";
        this.Password = "61-64-6D-69-6E";
        this.PermissionsList = new PCMS2(); // OR new PCMS1, as I will explain in a bit

    }
}
```

The problematic bit: consider two implementations of PCMS class, PCMS1 and PCMS2:

```
public class PCMS1
{
    public PermissionObject p1, p2;

    public PCMS1()
    {
        p1 = new PermissionObject("ImportConfigCMS", "tsmiImportCMSConfigFile", true);
        p2 = new PermissionObject("ExportConfigCMS", "tsmiExportCMSConfigFile", true);
    }
}

public class PCMS2
{
    public List<PermissionObject> listOfPermissions = new List<PermissionObject>();

    public PCMS2()
    {
        listOfPermissions.Add(new PermissionObject("ImportConfigCMS", "tsmiImportCMSConfigFile", true));
        listOfPermissions.Add(new PermissionObject("ExportConfigCMS", "tsmiExportCMSConfigFile", true));
    }
}
```

And finally main class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Config Con;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Con = Config.Load();
        if (Con == null)
        {
            Con = new Config();
            Con.cmsDataPath = @"E:\testconpcms.xml";
            Con.Save();
        }
        if (Con.usersCMS.Count == 0)
        {
            UserClass adminDefault = new UserClass();
            Con.usersCMS.Add(adminDefault);
            Con.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, using either `PCMS1` or `PCMS2`, the config file generates properly - one user with 2 permissions.

However, when config file is present, calling `Con = Config.Load()` in the main class gives different results.

Using `PCMS1`, the `Con` object is as expected - 1 user with 2 permissions.

However, using `PCMS2`, the `Con` object is 1 user with 4 (four) permissions. It doubles that field (it's basically p1, p2, p1, p2). Put a BP to see Con after `Load()`.

I guess the list (`PCMS2`) implementation is doing something wonky during load which I'm not aware of, but I can't seem to find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You creates your permission objects in constructor of `PMCS2` you do it in the constructor of `PMCS1` too, but there you do have two properties that will be overwritten by serializer.
In case of of `PMCS2` your constructor adds two items to List and than serializer adds the items it has deserilized to the same list.

I don't know exactly your usecase but i would suggest to move init of the permissions to separated method:

```
public class PCMS1
{
    public PermissionObject p1, p2;

    public void Init()
    {
        p1 = new PermissionObject("ImportConfigCMS", "tsmiImportCMSConfigFile", true);
        p2 = new PermissionObject("ExportConfigCMS", "tsmiExportCMSConfigFile", true);
    }
}

public class PCMS2
{
    public List<PermissionObject> listOfPermissions = new List<PermissionObject>();

    public void Init()
    {
        listOfPermissions.Add(new PermissionObject("ImportConfigCMS", "tsmiImportCMSConfigFile", true));
        listOfPermissions.Add(new PermissionObject("ExportConfigCMS", "tsmiExportCMSConfigFile", true));
    }
}
```

after that you could call it, if you want to get initial settings:

```
if (Con.usersCMS.Count == 0)
{
    UserClass adminDefault = new UserClass();
    adminDefault.PermissionsList.Init();
    Con.usersCMS.Add(adminDefault);
    Con.Save();
}
```

Comment: This seems to generate empty permission list when I run it to generate config file.

Comment: @Janushoff  sorry, have missunderstood your code, i updated answer with the right place to call init

Comment: Yep, this now works properly, altho I'm still having some difficulties of why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: @Janushoff cosntructor of eh object was called by a serializer, you could see it if you place breakpoint in the constructor of PCMS2, so constructor adds 2 items to the list and than serializer adds 2 items to the list. At the end you have 4 items there.